# Multi Tenant Django Backend

Tags: django, jwt, multi-tenant, djoser

HI All I am working on a multi-tenant backend.
I have nextjs frontend and django.

I have tried to have a single db approach where each user has a foreign key to a tenant he/she belongs to.  This seems like an easy way to handle multi tenancy but
Simple JWT nor djoser is NOT extendable enough to handle the multi tenancy this way.

So I have created a version of the same app using postgre schemas but that has the same issue with APIs where where you can not control the schemas if you are using djoser. UNLESS you download the whole lib and convert it to handle multischemas

So that leaves me with 2 other options

One: Have a seperate DB for each subdomain. This works but it means i have to have an open connection to each database. and have multiple DBs and migrations will be a nightmare.

and the other one is having a docker running for each subdomain and use nxing to do a reverse proxy this also work.

Question is would downloads all the apis and tweak them to your needs and have a huge code base and a ton of stuff to maintain.

Or Use the libs/apis but implemen it using the more expensive methods.

Thanks in advance for your inputs?

Comment: Maybe this will help you along the way: 1. https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/ 2. https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ 3. https://medium.com/@techWithAditya/scaling-your-saas-with-django-mastering-multi-tenant-architecture-with-separate-databases-per-cb39311fe4d7

Comment: I went through those already and that is how I tried all 4 versions of the same project but does not really talk about my issue which is how to  django libraries (like djoser) when you have multi tenant multi user.